# Splitting A Hash Into Multiple Unordered Lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, html-lists, grouping, blueprint-css

I have been searching in vain to accomplish the following in a more clean manner.

I have a hash of strings which I am calling from my controller:

```
@categories = Category.find
```

and I am trying to display the results in three separate unordered lists (ul).

The following is an ugly version of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<div class="span-7">
    <ul>
    <% @categories.first(4).each do |category| %>

        <li><%= category.name %></li>

    <% end %>
    </ul>       
</div>

<div class="span-7">
    <ul>
    <% @categories[5..8].each do |category| %>

        <li><%= category.name %></li>

    <% end %>
    </ul>       
</div>

<div class="span-8 last">
    <ul>
    <% @categories[9..12].each do |category| %>

        <li><%= category.name %></li>

    <% end %>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

(Note: I am using BlueprintCSS, thus the excess of "span-x")

I think there is a cleaner way to do this using grouping (http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html) but I can't figure out how to tie all of this together.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

(I am using Rails 3.0.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. This should do what you want.

```
<% category_count = 0 %>
<% @categories.in_groups_of(4) do |group| %>
  <% category_count += group.size %>
  <div class="<%= category_count == @categories.size ? "span-8 last" : "span-7" %>">
    <ul>
    <% group.each do |category| %>
      <% if category %>
      <li><%= category.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>       
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You might have to do some trickery to figure out how to add the "last" class to the final div... I'll ponder that.

Comment: There we go. Counting the categories as we iterate should do it.

Comment: That got me closer but I now getting an error: 

`undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` where name is referring to `category.name`

Comment: Thank you for continued help on this, sorry to be a pain. @categories isn't empty as judged by the output from `debug @categories`

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. #in_groups_of fills the array with nil by default, so you need to check to see if category is nil in the inner loop. I'll update the answer.